# understanding javascript function call

Tags: javascript

still learning to javascript. How does this below code work?
when `main(params)` is called does it mean it under-the-hood calls `dowork(callbackXYZ, options, params)` ?

```
const { dowork } = require('some_lib');

async function callbackXYZ(src, tgt, params) => {
    // ...logic
}
const main = dowork(callbackXYZ, options);
await main(params);
```

Comment: `dowork` probably returns a `function`, which you call with `params`.

Comment: There's no way to tell from the snippet what happens inside the function that `doworks` returns. It depends on what's in `some_lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified code example. It removes the async stuff, since it's not needed to understand.

```js
// The callback you provide to `dowork`
// The internals of `dowork` will give invoke it with the given args
function callbackXYZ(src, tgt, params) {
   console.log("src is:", src);
   console.log("tgt is:", tgt);
   console.log("params is:", params);
}

// The options you provide to `dowork`
var options = {src: "foo", tgt: "bar"};

// Invoking `dowork` receives your callback and options, and returns
// a new function that has access to both of these arguments.
const main = dowork(callbackXYZ, options);

// The params you provide to the returned function
const params = {my: "params"};

// Invoking the returned function
main(params);


// Here's the `dowork`. It receives your callback and options, and it
// returns a new function that expects you to pass it params.
// So that returned function has reference to the callback, options
// and params.
// The body of the returned function, simply invokes your callback and
// passes it data from the options and params you provided
function dowork(callback, opts) {
  return function(params) {
    callback(opts.src, opts.tgt, params);
  }
}
```

So `dowork` receives your `callbackXYZ` and the `opts` and returns a function that you can invoke, passing in the `params`.

When you invoke that returned function, and pass it the `params`, that returned function invokes your original callback, and passes it data both from the `options` and the `params`.

Comment: Thanks @slappy for the detailed explanation. Got it. Is this a common javascript pattern?  You immediately(correctly) recognized that `dowork(...)` was returning function.

Comment: @gkucmierz @slappy to me it looks like a way to provide flexibility. i.e the caller can write their own `callbackXYZ`  and `dowork()` can invoke it. That is obvious. But `dowork()` returning a function and and then caller calling that function seems like additional hops.

Comment: Yes, passing functions around (including returning them) is very common. Because functions will "remember" the original variable scope where they're created *(they create a closure)*, they're handy for associating some data with a function that continuously operates with that data.

Answer (score 0):

No!

- `dowork` is function which returns another function
- that another function is assigned to `const main`
- then this main (function which returns promise) is called

You can also run this code without declaring anything:

```js
...
await dowork(callbackXYZ, options)(params);
```

Comment: And what `dowork()` does with all these parameters depends on the design of the library.